# Правильно ли оформлено предложение с точки зрения стилистики и пунктуации?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, стилистика

На нём не было рубашки, только брюки, и стоял он босиком в снегу. 
Правильно ли оформлено предложение с точки зрения стилистики( например:  вторая часть требует дополнительного слова?) и пунктуации( мне кажется, что между частями предложения должны стоять запятые, так как это части сложного предложения). Помогите разобраться, права ли я?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, всё действительно верно. **Только брюки** здесь выступает в качестве очередного простого предложения, причём неполного. Сравните:

**На нём не было рубашки, *были* только брюки.**

Однако постановка, например, тире, тоже будет верной. Это обусловлено постановкой логического ударения, подчёркивающего тот факт, что человек был одет в одни брюки. Вот само предложение, если что:

**На нём не было рубашки — только брюки, и стоял он босиком в снегу.**

Comment: Вариант с тире  даже предпочтительнее, так как увеличенная пауза подчеркивает  присоединительный характер второго предложения.

Comment: Думаю, что отмеченная в ответе неполнота второго предложения - решающая причина для постановки тире: оно замещает опущенный член этого предложения.

Comment: Да, тире меняет предложение в лучшую сторону. Спасибо большое всем...

Comment: Вот это вы даёте... +245 очков... Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Всё здесь нормально, и пунктуация тоже в порядке. А что-то изменить всегда можно – ибо вылизывать можно до бесконечности.